Gitlab Webhook Trigger Active-Active Jenkins
Problem
I have a Jenkins service that is of active-active architecture, in which the same url denote as https://test-jenkins.ocado.com can route to any one of two Jenkins servers.
Whenever there is a change to a Gitlab repository, I want the associated webhook to trigger this Jenkins service.
On Jenkins under the pipeline Transformer to be triggered, I go to Configuration -> General -> Build Triggers -> check Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL: https://test-jenkins.ocado.com/project/Transformer -> Have the default ticks of Push Events, etc. -> Under Advanced I have to generate a Secret Token as I find leaving it blank does not work.
On GitLab's side I go to the repo and webhook settings, then input this url https://test-jenkins.ocado.com/project/Transformer, under Secret Token I enter the one generated by Jenkins.
It works fine if I only want the webhook to trigger one Jenkins server. However, I am only allowed to enter one Secret Token in the GitLab webhook trigger, am not allowed to make the Secret Token on both Jenkins servers to be the same as it must be generated by Jenkins, and in an active-active architecture, this trigger would only work for one Jenkins server, but not the other one that may be routed to.
I want the GitLab webhook to work for active-active Jenkins, such that the call to both Jenkins servers would be valid from webhook trigger.
My Attempt
I tried using the Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts) option on Jenkins, instead of the Build when a change is pushed to GitLab.
Here I am given a field Authentication Token that I can manually set to be the same on both Jenkins, let's say I set it to "abc".
It says near the field box:
"Use the following URL to trigger build remotely: JENKINS_URL/job/Transformer/build?token=TOKEN_NAME or /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME
Optionally append &cause=Cause+Text to provide text that will be included in the recorded build cause."
So on GitLab, I tried to set the webhook URL as https://test-jenkins.ocado.com/build/Transformer?token=abc, and leave the Secret Token field empty.
Yet, it gives me the error of
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403 
Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

